# React native mobileSDK smartsync sync up 'succeeds' without actually changing anything

Tags: mobile, react-native, smartsync

I am trying to sync data created in a mobile app (currently iOS, but I've had exactly the same problems with smartsync on Android before).

I have a local soup registered that includes a field with `path = '__local__'` and `type = 'string'`

The name of the soup is the same as the name of an Object in Salesforce, and all the field names match exactly.

I am calling smartsync.syncUp with exactly the same parameters as in [the example](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SmartSyncExplorerReactNative). That is:

```
smartsync.syncUp(false,
                {}, 
                $(OBJECT_NAME), 
                {mergeMode: smartsync.MERGE_MODE.OVERWRITE, 
                 fieldlist: [$(COMMA_SEPARATED_PATHS)]}, 
                (res) => {
                    console.log("Successfully synced to server. Result: ");
                    console.log(res);
                }, (err) => {
                    console.log("syncUp failed with error: " + err); 
                });
```

This results in the 'success' callback being called with an object that seems to reflect the options and fieldlist I provided, but with `totalSize = 0`. None of the changes are reflected in Salesforce.

Has anyone else ever had this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any rows in your soup?

A row that you would expect to "sync up" to salesforce should look like the following:

```
{ 
  __local__: true, 
  __locally_created__: true, 
  __locally_updated__: false, 
  __locally_deleted__: false, 
  attributes: { type: 'MySObject__c' } 
}
```

The important components here are `__local__`, `__locally_created__`, and `attributes`. Local tells smartsync that the object is something that needs to sync, locally created tells smartsync that the type of sync that needs to happen is an insert operation. Attributes/type/mysobject__c tells smartsync that the type of SObject that needs to be created is `MySObject__c`.

Comment: Thanks, the issue was that I missed the attributes part in the soup rows. Sorry for the late reply, I also ran into an unrelated issue that slowed me down a bit.